# Why is %00 NULL an invalid character in a URL and causes a browser to crash?

Tags: url, null

I know that NULL is used to terminate a string, but why is it an invalid character in a URL? [The Wikipedia page for NULL character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character#:%7E:text=A%20null%20character%20can%20be,the%20end%20of%20the%20string.) states that a NULL character can be placed in a URL code using %00. So doesn't this mean it is legal?

If the NULL character is present in a URL either in the middle or at the end, won't it just be acting as a terminating character? Why should it be invalid?

My questions maybe better understood with the following examples:

Example 1: https://a4%00 would mean that the string is essentially "a4"

Example 2: https://a45xxc%00fbbg --> over here, is the string only read till "c"?

Answer (score 0):

Its problably because a lot of other data after the url wil be used so it'll be complicated for browsers to work with the null character.
However, you can still use the null character in API because they dont have to deal with the character.
Example
`curl https://google.com/%00 (some data)`